# Embeds_many child property not persisted when saving parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, mongodb, api, mongoid

I've been looking for some days without finding the exact answer to my problem which is as simple as that : I have a simple model, with books and authors. A book embeds many authors, and an author is embedded in book. But whenever I'm saving a new book, the author array is not persisted.

What I have is an angular 7 application, calling a ROR API. My Rails versions is 5.2.2. I am using mongoid 7.0 for persistence.

My API was generated with rails g scaffold, and with the --api and --skip-active-record flags.

I first had a problem with the mapping of my properties. My Angular APP sends JSON in lowerCamelCase, when Rails awaits form lower_snake_case vars. I managed to bypass this problem by adding a middleware (correct me if I'm wrong on this one) in my initializers which converts camelCase to snake_case.

```
# Transform JSON request param keys from JSON-conventional camelCase to
# Rails-conventional snake_case:
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:json] = -> (raw_post) {
   # Modified from action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb
   data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)
   data = {:_json => data} unless data.is_a?(Hash)

   # Transform camelCase param keys to snake_case:
   data.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)
}
```

From what I found looking for my problem, it could have been a problem with strong params, so I tried to get awat with this in my book_params

```
def book_params
  #params.fetch(:book, {})
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :release_date, authors_attributes: [:name, :last_name, :birth_date])
end
```

These are my model :

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :birth_date, type: Date
end

class Author < Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :book
end

class Book
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :title, type: String
 field :release_date, type: Date
 embeds_many :authors 
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
end
```

And this is POST in my book controller (generated with Rails)

```
  # POST /books
  def create

    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if @book.save
      render json: @book, status: :created, location: @book
    else
      render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

And here are exemple of a body sent, received and how it is processed by Rails :

[Request sent by angular app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYXjM.png)

[Request received and processed by Rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idwzu.png)

We can see in the book object

```
"book"=>{"title"=>"azerty", "release_date"=>"2019-01-21T16:10:19.515Z"}}
```

That the authors have disappeared, though they were present in the request received by the server.

My question is then : what is the solution to this, or at least what am I missing ? Doesn't Mongoid automatically save children when using embedded documents and **accepts_nested_attributes_for** ? Should I manually save the children each time a parent is saved in my controller ?

Thanks in advance for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested attributes to save children records

Add following line in `book` model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
```

And pass authors parameters in `author_attributes`, for exa:

```
{title: 'test', release_date: '', author_attributes: [{first_name: '', other_attributes of author}, {first_name: '', , other_attributes of author}]}
```

for more details please check [Mongoid: Nested attributes](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html)

Pass perameters in this format

```
{"title"=>"test", "release_date"=>"2019-01-22", "book"=>{"title"=>"test", "release_date"=>"2019-01-22", "authors_attributes"=>[{"first_name"=>"test name", "last_name"=>"test", "birth_date"=>"2019-01-22T09:43:39.698Z"}]}}
```

Permit book params

```
def book_params
   params.require(:book).premit(:first_name, :last_name, authors_attributes: %i[first_name last_name birth_date])
end
```

Comment: I've tried this, I already had `accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors`, I tried to change "authors" to "author_attributes" or "authors_attributes" in my request, yet the problem remains.

Comment: Can you please show me your server log when you are requesting to create book?

Comment: I added some logs in the bottom of my original post but here you go with what you requested 

`Started POST "/books/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-22 11:18:53 +0100
Processing by BooksController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"title"=>"test", "release_date"=>"2019-01-22", "authors_attributes"=>[{"first_name"=>"test name", "last_name"=>"test", "birth_date"=>"2019-01-22T09:43:39.698Z"}], "book"=>{"title"=>"test", "release_date"=>"2019-01-22"}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | home_library_development.insert | STARTED | {"insert"=>"books", "ordered"=>true, "lsid"=>{"id"=>......`

Comment: `authors_attributes` should be under `book` params

Comment: Like this way `Parameters: {"title"=>"test", "release_date"=>"2019-01-22", "book"=>{"title"=>"test", "release_date"=>"2019-01-22", "authors_attributes"=>[{"first_name"=>"test name", "last_name"=>"test", "birth_date"=>"2019-01-22T09:43:39.698Z"}]}}`

Comment: @Thr I have updated ans, let me know still you have any question
I hope edited answer will work for you.

Comment: So I finally found the solution

In fact, I misread a part of the documentation which stated that you don't have to wrap your object in your "object" in the latests versions of Rails. But in reality you still have to.

I removed my inheritance between Authors and Persons, to simplify, and removed **accepts_nested_attributes_for**. 
My strong params are like so : `params.require(:book).permit(:title, :release_date, authors: [:first_name, :last_name, :birth_date])`

And my request : `{"book":{"title": "test", "release_date": "2019-01-22", "authors": [ { "first_name": "test name", etc...`